# How do I display static images that are in content variable in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a django site where a portion is basically a CMS. There are large content blocks (like the content of a post) held in a database and within those I need to display images that are in my static files. The content within the content block could be anything just like a regular blog post so there may be images scattered within it.

I am displaying the content in a template using the following

```
{{content | safe}}
```

I can display the images if I put the full url but that is not optimal as it doesn't use the advantages of the Django static files system. How do I go about displaying these since I can't use the `{% static %}` tag for the images that are within the content?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a place to use a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).  There are probably a lot of different ways to do it, but one could look like this:

```
from django import template
from my_project import settings

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def img_link(content):
    return content.replace('src=','src='+settings.STATIC_URL')
```

That's assuming you already have the code in your content look something like  -- you can adjust the filter to meet however your images are actually written in the content.  Because this is relying on the STATIC_URL from your settings, it will adjust whenever the URL is changed, exactly as {% static %} would.

of course, filters can be [chained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#filters), so you could just write `{{content|safe|img_link}}` to activate the filter.